# HTTP GET Request method sends '?' instead of '/'

Tags: angular, swagger, nestjs, xmlhttprequest

I have generic method to communicate with my Swagger API:

```
  get<ReturnType>(url: string, params?: HttpParams): Observable<ReturnType> {
    return this.http.get<ReturnType>(environment.apiUrl + url, {
      params: params,
    });
  }
```

But when I make request with params it tries to reach this endpoint `http://localhost:3000/user/get?id=10` instead of `http://localhost:3000/user/get/10`

On the backend side there is:

```
    @Get('get/:id')
    @ApiResponse({ type: UserDto, status: 201 })
    getUser(@Param('id') id: number): UserDto {
      return { id: id, name: 'John Doe', email: 'john.doe@example.com' };
    }
```

Where is mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are passing the `id` into `HttpParams` and `HttpParams` is used to build the parameters as a query string. Thus the `id` is shown as query string parameter instead of path. You should construct the URL as: *get<T>(`/user/get/${id}`, null)* and not using the `HttpParams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to use query parameters over url parameters. Remove the `:id` from the `@Get()` and use `@Query('id')` instead of `@Param('id')`. Everything else should be fine once you update the get request

Comment: The solution helped, I actually overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you are sending `id` as a query string parameter instead of a path.

I believe that currently you are calling the `get` method as below:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
  .set("id", id);

let obs: Observable<T> = /* service */.get<T>("/user/get", params);
```

To send the `id` as a path, you should construct the URL as "/user/get/10" and not use the `HttpParams`.

```
let obs: Observable<T> = /* service */.get<T>(`/user/get/${id}`, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a pathvariable to url instead of Request Params, if you want to get this url - `http://localhost:3000/user/get/{id}`

use this,

```
 get<ReturnType>(url: string, id:any): Observable<ReturnType> {
    return this.http.get<ReturnType>(`${base_url}/user/get/${id}`);
  }
```